# reloadData() calls cellForRowAtIndexPath for every cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I'm having this issue that when reloadData() is called after the initial API call, it calls `willDisplayCell` method which when the last cell is displayed will load more data (API returns 10 data at a time).
However in the view it can show only 4 - 5 cells as I set the row height to 175 points manually. Does anyone know why is this happening?
If this is how the tableView works what can I do to make my tableView to load only 10 initially?

Following is my code.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var tableView: UITableView!
    var photoViewmodel: PhotoViewModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Home"
        initTableView()

        photoViewmodel = PhotoViewModel()
        photoViewmodel.loadNewPhotos {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func initTableView() {
        tableView = UITableView.init(frame: self.view.frame, style: .plain)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = 175
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: HomeTableViewCell.identifier)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photoViewmodel.photos.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cellForRowAt")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: HomeTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.configureCell(url: photoViewmodel.photos[indexPath.row].regularImgUrl, cacheKey: indexPath.row)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("willDisplay")
        let lastCell = photoViewmodel.photos.count - 1
        if indexPath.row == lastCell {
            print("add 10 more photos")
            photoViewmodel.loadNewPhotos(
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here, can you edit the question for clarity please? When you say "Does anyone know why is this happening?" which bit specifically are you referring to? Thank you @bg_k

Comment: Thanks for commenting @TheMotherofJosephBeuys
When the app runs, it loads data and then executes `reloadData()`, and it seems `reloadData()` somehow calls `willDisplayCellforRowAt` method and satisfies `if indexPath.row == lastCell` so it will load one more set of data, in total there will be 20 data initially loaded.
As I mentioned above, the row height is pretty tall so there's no way to display all 10 rows at once and not sure why it works like this...